# ¿Cuándo usar std::move y por qué?

Tags: c++, c++11

¿En qué escenarios es recomendable usar `std::move`?

```
std::vector<int> func()
{
  std::vector<int> toReturn(1000000,5);
  return std::move(toReturn); // 1
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> datos = std::move(func()); // 2

  // operaciones varias
}
```

En el ejemplo anterior, ¿Son correctos los usos de `std::move`? ¿Por qué? ¿Qué efectos puede tener un mal uso de std::move?

Comment: C++11 su uso evita las copia, la representación interna es simplemente movido, desventaja de no usarlo es que tendra alguna copia adicional por ahi, su uso permite la transferencia eficiente de los recursos de O a otro objeto. Tambien puede emplearlo para algunos objetos no copiables, como un unique_ptr, sobre un mal uso no sabria decirle. Saludos

Comment: por otro lado me parece un poco extraño esto -> std::vector<int> datos = std::move(func()); quizas deberia ser -> std::vector<int> datos = func();, pero no sabria decirle si eso es del todo correcto. saludos

Comment: Es algo que funciona pero que no es lo más recomendable. La idea central de la pregunta es precisamente aportar luz sobre este tema, ya que es una herramienta bastante potente si se utiliza correctamente.

Comment: ami me parece buena pregunta, siento no poder responderla como respuesta, pues no tengo conocimiento para hacerlo de forma segura, por  eso le dije lo que sabia y lo que me parecia extraño, espero ayude a una mejor respuesta saludos

Comment: dando vueltas a ese codigo tenia unas dudas, revisando unos apuntes, (RVO return-value-optimization) Todos los valores de retorno ya se mueven bien optimizados no hay necesidad de moverlos de manera explícita con valores de retorno. Saludos

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**¿Qué hace `std::move`?**

`std::move` convierte un `Lvalue` en un `Rvalue`.

**¿Para qué sirve `std::move`?**

C++11 añade un nuevo constructor al catálogo. Su firma sería `POO(POO&&)`. Este constructor, si se ha definido, se invoca automáticamente cuando se recibe un `Rvalue`y su función es traspasar el estado de un objeto a otro, evitando realizar una copia del mismo.

C++11 también permite utilizar un nuevo operador de asignación, cuya firma sería `POO& operator=(POO&&)`.

Estas dos nuevas características pueden convivir sin problemas con el constructor copia y la asignación de toda la vida. Únicamente hay que tener en cuenta que implementar el constructor copia deshabilita la implementación por defecto del constructor `move` y viceversa. Lo anterior es aplicable también al operador de asignación.

Esto puede suponer una importante mejora de rendimiento en el caso de objetos pesados. Un ejemplo:

```
class ObjetoPesado
{
  private:

    const int NumDatos = 1000000;
    int* _datos;

  public:

    ObjetoPesado()
      : _datos(new int[NumDatos])
    {
    }

    ObjetoPesado(ObjetoPesado&& origen)
      : _datos(nullptr)
    {
      std::swap(_datos,origen._datos);
    }

    ObjetoPesado(const ObjetoPesado& origen)
      : ObjetoPesado() // Llamada al constructor por defecto,
                       // soportado desde C++11
    {
      std::copy(origen._datos,
                origen._datos+NumDatos,
                _datos);
    }

    ~ObjetoPesado()
    {
      delete[] _datos;
    }
};

int main()
{
  clock_t start = clock();
  for( auto i=0; i<10000; i++ )
  {
    ObjetoPesado origen;
    ObjetoPesado* copia = new ObjetoPesado(origen); // Constructor copia
    delete copia;
  }
  std::cout << "copia: " << static_cast<double>(clock()-start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;

  start = clock();
  for( auto i=0; i<10000; i++ )
  {
    ObjetoPesado origen;
    ObjetoPesado* copia = new ObjetoPesado(std::move(origen)); // Constructor move
    delete copia;
  }
  std::cout << "move: " << static_cast<double>(clock()-start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;
}
```

Aunque pueda parecer obvio que copiar un puntero de un sitio a otro es mucho más ligero que copiar toda la memoria involucrada queda más claro si se ejecuta el ejemplo. Ejecutando este código en release, en mi máquina da los siguientes tiempos:

```
copia: 22.929
move: 0.034
```

También queda claro que la sintaxis move únicamente interesa implementarla si el objeto hace uso (directo o indirecto) de memoria dinámica ya que esta mejora es aplicable únicamente a punteros.

La pega de utilizar `std::move` es que el objeto original pierde su estado. Normalmente esto no debería suponer un problema ya que la invocación de esta semántica no es aleatoria.

**¿Cuándo se debe usar std::move?**

La sintaxis `move`, como bien indicó @Angel-Angel, se puede ejecutar de forma automática al llamar a `return`. Esto es algo que debería formar parte del catálogo de optimizaciones de los compiladores actuales. Las siguientes dos funciones serían, en este caso, equivalentes.

```
ObjetoPesado func1()
{
  ObjetoPesado toReturn;
  return toReturn;
}

ObjetoPesado func2()
{
  ObjetoPesado toReturn;
  return std::move(toReturn);
}
```

Pero entonces, si `std::move` ya se suele invocar de forma implícita, ¿Cuándo hay que usarlo?

Lo más habitual es que esta función se use sobretodo en las implementaciones de los constructores y las asignaciones `move`, ya que nos aseguramos que los objetos anidados se benefician de esta optimización:

```
class POO
{
  private:
    std::string _cadena;

  public:

    POO(POO&& original)
      : _cadena(std::move(original._cadena)) // Invocamos el constructor
                                             // move de std::string
    { }
};
```

También es necesario utilizarlo cuando se trabaja con `std::unique_ptr`. En especial cuando éste se encuentran en contenedores. Si queremos extraer o insertar un `std::unique_ptr` en un vector a lo bestia el programa directamente no compilará:

```
int main()
{
  std::unique_ptr<int> ptr(new int(1));
  *ptr = 100;

  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> datos;
  datos.push_back(ptr);            // ERROR
  datos.push_back(std::move(ptr)); // OK
  datos.push_back(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(10)); // OK porque es un Rvalue

  std::cout << *datos[0] << std::endl;
}
```

**¿Qué sucede si es aplica la sintaxis `move` sobre un objeto que no tiene implementado el constructor `move`?**

Lo que sucede es que si no se encuentra el constructor `move`, el compilador intentará llamar al constructor copia. Si este tampoco se encuentra entonces se producirá un error en tiempo de compilación.

Es decir, aplicar la sintaxis `move` sobre un objeto que no está preparado para ello no debería tener consecuencias negativas tanto en términos de funcionalidad como de rendimiento.

Una vez explicado todo esto y volviendo al código de la pregunta inicial:

```
std::vector<int> func()
{
  std::vector<int> toReturn(1000000,5);
  return std::move(toReturn); // 1
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> datos = std::move(func()); // 2

  // operaciones varias
}
```

Queda claro que el valor añadido de la sintaxis en ambos casos es nulo, si bien podría darse la circunstancia de que el uso `1` pueda ser necesario en aquellos extraños casos en los que el compilador no aplique optimizaciones en los valores de retorno.

Comment: perfectamente explicado

Answer (score 1):

Buenísima la explicación de Eferion, he querido comentar en su explicación pero aún no puedo; me gustaría no obstante añadir algo a su explicación.

Desde C++11, cuando el compilador encuentra un `return`, convierte el objeto de retorno en un `Rvalue;` por lo que se llama al construtor move, o al operador de asignación, dependiendo del caso.

Así que no es necesario hacer

```
ObjetoPesado func()
{
  ObjetoPesado obj;
  // ...
  return std::move(obj);
}
```

Fuente: http://cppactual.blogspot.com/2016/04/entendiendo-la-sintaxis-move.html

Comment: Gracias por tus comentarios. Lo que comentas está en línea con la optimización [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), por lo que no siempre se va a llamar al constructor *move*. Comentar eso puede ser complicado de explicar y confundir al lector