# Borrar elementos de una lista representada en un QTabWidget

Tags: c++, qt

Tengo una clase `MainWindow` derivada de `QMainWindow`

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:

    struct MetaObra
    {
        InterfazObra* miobra;
        QString nombrefichero;
        MetaObra():miobra(nullptr){}
    };
    std::list<MetaObra>ListaObras;
    std::list<MetaObra>::iterator obraActual;
.........................
}
```

Cuando añado un elemento del tipo MetaObra a la lista, una pestaña de un `QTabWidget` aparece. Cuando cambio la pestaña activa el iterador apunta a la MetaObra de la lista....hasta ahí todo bien.
El problema lo tengo a la hora de cerrar pestañas, si cierro una pestaña que no sea la última, el iterador va a la siguiente pestaña, pero cuando quiero cerrar esa, el programa falla y se cierra.

Este sería el código para cerrar las pestañas:

```
void MainWindow::ActionCerrar()
{   
    std::list<MetaObra>::iterator obraBorrar = obraActual;    
    if (ListaObras.size()>1)
    {

        if (obraActual!=ListaObras.end() && std::next(obraActual)==ListaObras.end())//ultimo elemento
        {

            obraActual=std::prev(obraActual);
        }
        else
        {
            obraActual=std::next(obraActual);
        }
    }
    delete obraBorrar->miobra;
    ListaObras.erase(obraBorrar);
}
```

Lo que hago primero es comprobar si hay más de un elemento en la lista. Si es así, compruebo si es el último. Si es el último pongo el iterador en el elemento anterior. Si no lo es lo pongo en el elemento siguiente.
Luego procedo a borrar el contenido del puntero y por último saco al elemento de la lista. He comprobado el comportamiento y es el correcto.

Imaginad que tengo 3 obras, una en cada pestaña.Obra1,Obra2,Obra3.
Si cierro la pestaña de la Obra2, se me pone la Obra3 como pestaña activa. Si la cierro entonces, el programa falla. Sin embargo, si antes de cerrar la pestaña cambio a Obra1 como pestaña activa y luego vuelvo a Obra3, se cierra normalmente. Cuando cierro las pestañas en orden decreciente no hay problemas, pero sí si las cierro de "izquierda a derecha"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es más sencillo que lo que estás intentando.

`std::list::erase` devuelve un iterador al siguiente elemento de la lista. La idea entonces es borrar sí o sí el elemento y verificar si el iterador devuelto es el final de lista. Si eso sucede y resulta que la lista tiene elementos basta con retroceder dicho iterador una posición para obtener el iterador a una pestaña válida:

```
void MainWindow::ActionCerrar()
{
  if( obraBorrar != ListaObras.end() ) // Es necesario este chequeo?
  {
    delete obraBorrar->miObra;
    obraBorrar = ListaObras.erase(obraBorrar);

    if ( obraBorrar == ListaObras.end() && !ListaObras.empty() )
      obraBorrar = std::prev(obraBorrar);
  }
}
```

Eso sí, considera implementar un destructor para la estructura y poder evitar así del `delete`:

```
struct MetaObra
{
    InterfazObra* miobra;
    QString nombrefichero;
    MetaObra():miobra(nullptr){}
    ~MetaObra(){ delete miobra; }
};

void MainWindow::ActionCerrar()
{
  if( obraBorrar != ListaObras.end() ) // Es necesario este chequeo?
  {
    // delete obraBorrar->miObra; ya no es necesario
    obraBorrar = ListaObras.erase(obraBorrar);

    if ( obraBorrar == ListaObras.end() && !ListaObras.empty() )
      obraBorrar = std::prev(obraBorrar);
  }
}
```

---

**Edito:** La solución anterior puede dar problemas si los elementos se insertan en la lista por copia (un posible ejemplo):

```
MetaObra obra;
// ...
ListaObras.insert(ListaObras.end(),obra);
```

Ya que con este diseño se estaría llamando al constructor copia de `MetaObra` para copiar el objeto en el contenedor y posteriormente se destruiría el objeto `obra`, que liberaría los recursos correspondientes.

Hay a grandes rasgos dos soluciones:

- Usar punteros en la lista. Esto elimina las copias de objetos y la destrucción de los mismos, pero obliga a usar memoria dinámica:

  ```
  std::list<MetaObra*> ListaObras;

  MetaObra* obra = new MetaObra();
  // ...
  ListaObras.insert(ListaObras.end(),obra); // Ya no hay copia de objetos sino de punteros
  ```
- Usar la *sintaxis move*:

  ```
  MetaObra obra;
  // ...
  ListaObras.insert(ListaObras.end(),std::move(obra));
  // A partir de este punto ya no se debe usar `obra`
  ```

  Si lo anterior no funciona de primeras es posible que haya que habilitar el *constructor move*. Como de primeras no debería ser necesario darle una funcionalidad específica se podría dejar con su implementación por defecto:

  ```
  struct MetaObra
  {
      MetaObra(MetaObra&&) = default; // Gracias a default no necesita implementacion

      // Operador de asignacion move
      MetaObra& operator=(MetaObra&&) = default;
  };
  ```

  La gran ventaja de esta solución es que evitas recurrir a la memoria dinámica... la gran desventaja es que hay que tener cuidado para no hacer copias del objeto que puedan destuir el puntero... quizás sería conveniente deshabilitar el constructor copia y el operador de asignación:

  ```
  struct MetaObra
  {
      MetaObra(MetaObra const&) = delete;

      // Operador de asignacion con copia
      MetaObra& operator=(MetaObra const&) = delete;
  };
  ```

  Así el compilador impedirá que se puedan crear copias de los objetos. Piensa que para usos puntuales siempre se puede recurrir a las referencias:

  ```
  MetaObra& obra = *ListaObras.begin(); // Suponemos que la lista no esta vacia
  obra.nombreFichero = "test"; // Se actualiza el nombre del elemento de la lista
  ```

  Para obtener más información sobre la *sintaxis move* puedes consultar el siguiente [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/854/cu%C3%A1ndo-usar-stdmove-y-por-qu%C3%A9/913#913)
- Usar punteros inteligentes (similar a la primera solución pero sin tener que lidiar directamente con la memoria dinámica):

  ```
  std::list<std::shared_ptr<MetaObra>> ListaObras;

  std::shared<MetaObra> obra = std::make_shared<MetaObra>();
  // ...
  ListaObras.insert(ListaObras.end(),obra);
  ```

  Esta solución permite crear copias de los punteros inteligentes. Ahora el objeto únicamente será destruído cuando ningún puntero inteligente lo esté referenciando.

  La desventaja de esta solución es que si no eres muy cuidadoso con el uso de los punteros puedes crear fugas de memoria.

Comment: Gracias eferion. El código lo he adaptado con unos mínimos cambios. El mayor problema que tengo es que si implemento el destructor la obra se borra automáticamente una vez creada, pero creo que (si no soy capaz de resolverlo sólo) es materia para otra pregunta diferente. Te muestro el código tuyo adaptado por mi.

Comment: @user3733164 lo que comentas del destructor te pasa por estar usando los objetos por valor... voy a editar la respuesta

Comment: @user3733164 ya está, con eso te debería funcionar correctamente el destructorç

Comment: gracias @eferion, como siempre una pedazo de respuesta que excede y amplía mis horizontes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, pues este sería el código adaptado de la función, según la respuesta de @eferion:

```
void MainWindow::ActionCerrar()
{   
    if (!ListaObras.empty())
    {
        std::list<MetaObra>::iterator obraBorrar = obraActual;
        {
            obraActual = ListaObras.erase(obraActual);
            delete obraBorrar->miobra;
            if ( obraActual == ListaObras.end() && !ListaObras.empty())
            {
                obraActual = std::prev(obraActual);
            }
        }
    }
}
```