# C++ - Llamar constructor dentro de otro

Tags: c++, poo, constructor

Tengo una clase `Ruleta` donde uno de sus atributos es un objeto de tipo `Crupier`. Necesito inicializar dicho objeto dentro del constructor de la clase `Ruleta`.

He intentado lo siguiente pero no funciona, así que agradecería si alguien me explica cuál es la manera correcta de hacerlo:

```
Ruleta(Crupier crupier); //en el .h

Ruleta::Ruleta(Crupier crupier)
{

crupier_=crupier("atributo1","atributo2"); //en el .cc (crupier_ es el atributo de tipo Crupier que tiene la clase Ruleta)

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La inicialización de variables miembro se **debería** realizar de esta otra forma:

```
Ruleta::Ruleta(Crupier crupier)
  : crupier_(crupier)
{
}
```

Ya que así se invoca únicamente el constructor copia de `Crupier`. Inicializar las variables miembro dentro de las llaves del constructor tiene sus implicaciones: primero se invoca el constructor por defecto de `Crupier` y, a continuación, se invoca el operador de asignación de `Crupier`.

Por otro lado, tal y como estás declarando el constructor de `Ruleta` **estás haciendo una copia innecesaria** de `crupier`, ya que pasas la variable por valor. En estos casos es mejor usar una referencia:

```
Ruleta::Ruleta(Crupier const& crupier)
```

O, si usas C++11 o superior y `Crupier` implementa el constructor adecuado, también puedes usar la [semántica de movimiento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/73843/463):

```
Ruleta::Ruleta(Crupier crupier)
  : crupier_(std::move(crupier))
{ }
```

Comment: Vale mencionar que ciertos tipos de variables *solo* se pueden inicializar así (referencias, constantes, non-constructibles por defecto).